# JFrame with dynamic modality

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have two JFrames.

One is the "main" Frame in which the User normally works. The second Frame is most of the time only there to give a better view of the data. The user clicks different Objects in the main Frame and the second Frame updates its View accordingly. (I actually have multiple of these "View"-Frames)
However I want the user to be able to edit the Data he sees in the second Frame as well.
I thought I would give him an "Edit"-Button in which he can enter an "Edit"-Mode which will move the second Frame into focus and temporarily "deactivate" the main Frame. He can leave the "Edit"-Mode with a "Save"-Button, which will reset the behavior to normal. Hence the main Frame gets the focus again and isn't "blocked" anymore
As I understand it i am not able to change the modality of an existing Frame.
The only solution I see at the moment would be to dispose (hide?) the second Frame and open a similar looking modal JDialog when the users presses "Edit". After Saving the JDialog is simply disposed.
Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Another possibility is to make another frame not editable (for example, put a dimming overlay using the [GlassPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)). In this case user can activate the frame, but cannot focus any component in the frame.

Comment: The better solution is to dump the 2nd frame completely and make it always a `JDialog`. See also [`Dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType-java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType-).

Comment: Right: that's what `JDialog`s are for

Comment: @AndrewThompson This I've found in the java-doc to the setModalityType: "Note: changing modality of the visible dialog may have no effect until it is hidden and then shown again."

Comment: I really like the Frame. The not modal Dialog always gets lost in the background and i can't use a modal Dialog (except when in Edit mode) because it will block my main Frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way that works for me.

I pass the main Frame instance to the second Frame and when the Edit-Button is pressed I setEnabled(false) on the main Frame.
Likewise I setEnabled(true) when the Save-Button is pressed.